# is there possible using manual recaptcha verification API in firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, captcha

I know firebase sdk have a built in function to verified recaptcha response before doing sign-in with phone number but,
it is possible using manual captcha verifier API return response from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify as 2nd parameter in firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phone, apiResponse) ?

I have different case to do it manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Recaptcha, you can introduce your own authorization method by using a decodable JWT as a second input. this will require a source of validation to generate the correct token

```js
    const captchaVerifier = {
      type: 'recaptcha',
      verify: () => Promise.resolve(token)
    };
```

Source: https://pastebin.com/kaCarKC5

You could also make your own ReCaptcha that triggers the invisible ReCaptcha or simply use invisible ReCaptcha and implement your own later on per your app's design.

Reference: [Invisible ReCaptcha](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-invisible-recaptcha)

Comment: Yes I'am aware with manual recaptcha implementation but I wonder about 2nd parameter of firebase method `firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phone, captchaVerifier)`. the firebase official sdk just showing 2nd parameter of above method with built-in `new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier()` from sdk. My requirement is to able passing captcha token response or object response from  `firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier().verify()` as 2nd parameter in  `firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phone, captchaVerifier)`

Comment: You can pass a decodable token into the captcha verifier: here is an example of it being used.
https://pastebin.com/kaCarKC5  - see lines 6 - 10

Comment: Thank you @DigiByte for the answer and it's work well.